# How to open .txt using windows explorer context menu in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, explorer

I am making a text editor for .html, .CSS, .js, .txt etc.
First I made my software in java swing and then I changed it to jar file then I changed it to exe file using launch4j and then I made it setup using innosetup but if I install this software and I right click on a file in windows explorer and choose open with and then I select my software and open it, it just open my software not the selected file so **how to do it?**

Comment: From memory, the selected file (path) will be passed to your `main` method via the `args` parameter

Comment: How to pass it?

Comment: It's passed to your program as "command line parameter" (by windows explorer)- you know, `public static void main(String[] args)` <- in there

Comment: so please give me a short example in code about it

Comment: No - the file reference (path/file name) will be passed to your program via the `main` methods argument list.  A simple test would be to print the the contents of `args` and see what you get.  Setting up an example which would be runnable would  be unnecessarily time consuming for me - since you already (apparently) have the code.  I'm also not running on Windows, so I'd not be able to test it, but I'm pretty sure (when I was), I did something similar

Comment: if i write `if(args[0]!=null) {//code to handle}` <- is this right?

Comment: Check the length of the args first - I'd first do a loop of the arguments and see what Windows sends you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will supply the path to the file as `args[0]` in your `main` method.

```
if(args.length > 0) {
    Path txt = Path.of(args[0]);
    //code to handle
}
```

Comment: what is `Path.of`? i am using netBeans IDE and there is no function like `Path.of` what is the reason

Comment: Use `import java.nio.file.Path;`. If you have older JDK you will need to use `Path txt = Paths.get(args[0])`